# Android: Stretch Bitmap to Polygon

Tags: android, canvas, path, bitmap, matrix

I have 4 points (no rectangle, just some polygon) and i want to draw (stretch, transform, skew, ...) a bitmap which fills that polygon... I guess it has to be done with a matrix - but is there a way to generate a matrix using 4 points? Or is there a way to fill a path with a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

Ok sorry for asking i've just solved it myself: Using [setPolyToPoly](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setPolyToPoly%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) works fine! :) I have no clue why i haven't seen it before...

Regards